# Environment variable not recognized when used for reusable workflow in github actions

Tags: github, environment-variables, runtime-error, github-actions, runtime-environment

In the below workflow github actions when I'm able to print and get the value of environment variable `XML_PATH` in a different JOB but the same variable `XML_PATH` errors as unrecognized when used in a different JOB having `reusable` workflow.

How is the job`(PRINT_VARS)`  having `reusable workflow` any different from a job`(READ_VARS_FROM_XML)` that `runs-on` when accessing variables like `XML_PATH`

```
---
name: CICD_RECYCLE

env:

  storeserver: "remotehost"
  REPO_NAME: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
  ENVIRONMENT: ${{ inputs.ENVIRONMENT }}
  XML_PATH: "\\\\$env:storeserver\\D$\\Jenkins\\$env:REPO_NAME\\$env:ENVIRONMENT"

on:

  push:
    branches:

      - "develop"

  workflow_dispatch:

    inputs:

      ENVIRONMENT:
        type: choice

        options:
          - qa
          - dev
          - test
          - prod

jobs:

  SETVARS:

    runs-on: 'mywindowsrunner'

    outputs:
#      outputxmlpath: $env:XML_PATH
      myvar: ${{ inputs.ENVIRONMENT }}

    steps:


      - name: Set environment variable for XML_PATH
        run: |
          echo "XML_PATH=$env:XML_PATH">> $env:GITHUB_ENV

  PRINT_VARS:

    needs:
      - SETVARS

    runs-on: 'mywindowsrunner'

    steps:

      - name: Powershell to export variables to ENVIRONMENT
        run: |
          echo "XML PATH: ${{ env.XML_PATH }}"

  READ_VARS_FROM_XML:

    needs:
      - SETVARS

    uses: mybank/betech/.github/workflows/extractfromxml.yml@mm365
    with:
      xml_Path: "${{ env.XML_PATH }}\\web.Parameters.xml"
#      xml_Path: '${{ needs.SETVARS.outputs.outputxmlpath }}'
    secrets: inherit
```

Output for `PRINT_VARS`:

> XML PATH: \remotehost\D$\Jenkins\betech\qa

Error for `READ_VARS_FROM_XML`:

```
    Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/main_recycle.yml#L85

The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main_recycle.yml (Line: 68, Col: 17): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.XML_PATH
```

As you can see in the output `${{ env.XML_PATH }}` prints the values fine in job `PRINT_VARS` whereas it errors when used in job `READ_VARS_FROM_XML`.

We can get the variable using `outputs` but I wanted to use `env` variables.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: See [limitations](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#limitations) of reusable workflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to pass the environment variables as the output of a job, like [here](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/2372#issuecomment-1591370444)